# How to remove right click context menu chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

As the title suggest, I am looking for script that i can add into my wordpress website that removes the right click context menu such as COPY, Copy Email Address, Copy Image Location and others.

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: It's not a good idea to stomp all over default browser behavior...

Comment: *"any ideas"*? Don't do it. If you have something on a website a user _will_ find a way to copy it.

Comment: Why do people immediately assume this is an attempt to secure the page? I'm personally looking for an answer to this question so I can provide a custom context menu similar to Google Maps.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira Because 'COPY, Copy Email Address, Copy Image Location'

Comment: Maybe he just wanted to remove those individual items from the default context menu and provide a better user experience. Sheesh...

Comment: Thank you all for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `event` called `oncontextmenu` that you can attatch to many objects . . .

For example . . .

> http://jsfiddle.net/Atn6e/

You'll have to create your own context menu to replace the one you're overriding though.

Comment: You should keep in mind though that this does not prevent people from disabling Js, using Plugins like FireBug etc. - it is still possible to get the data, it's only harder for non-technical people.

Comment: This was intended mainly as a hint to the OP.

Comment: thank you rbtLong and lethal-guitar for your helpful answer. Yes, I already thought of that before posting. the script or code is for the the non technical people.

Comment: this solution does not work in Google Chrome (v66). the context menu still appears.